# How can I define an elliptic neighborhood of image data point in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ellipse

I am a MATLAB beginner. I have an image data in MATLAB. I want to define an elliptic neighborhood for each point of this data. After that, I want to do some process in this neighborhood. How can I define this elliptic neighborhood for each point? please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to do some kind of convolution with a Gaussian filter?

Comment: it depends - which type of operations do you plan to do on this neighborhood?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question. To define ellipse you need to choose foci and sum distance from them. How would you choose them? are they fixed for all points in this data or do you want to choose a different ellipse for every point depending on image content? Please provide more information.

Comment: I want to do some kind of morphological operation in this neighborhood like erosion or dilation. these ellipses are different for every point depending on image content. you know I need elliptical adaptive structuring elements for morphological processing.